# Forming a view/reduce for couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I'm fairly new to couchDB and the concept of views and reduces, and I could not find anything that would help me get my data in the format I want to consume it in.

My Data - Each set is it's own document

```
{
    "_id": "2012-10-28",
    "scores" : [
        {
             "bob": 3,
             "dole": 5
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "2012-10-29",
    "scores" : [
        {
             "bob": 3,
             "dole": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like a view/reduce that returns something like:

```
"bob" : {
    "2012-10-27": 3,
    "2012-10-28": 3,
    ...
},
"dole": {
    "2012-10-27": 5,
    "2012-10-28": 6,
    ...
}
```

If this is not possible with my source data, I can reorganize it, but it will be tough.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I would also like to know of any good resources that explain the best practices for views and reduces.

Comment: Is all that data from your example in one document?

Comment: No, they are separate documents.  I updated the question to add physical separation between the entries to help clarify this.

Comment: Still no idea where documents start or end and where view rows start or end. Are some of the keys supposed to be document ids? Or view keys?

Comment: The first code block is two documents.  The second code block is an example of what I would like to get out of the view in the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless all the dates are known and you can hardcode them in the reduce function, I think it's a bit difficult to do what you need with map/reduce functions.

If it is ok to output something like:

```
{
  "key": ["bob", "2012-10-27"],
  "value": {"score": 3}
}
```

Then this `map` function should work:

```
var scoresMapFn = function (doc) {
  var scores = doc.scores[0];
  for (var k in scores) {
    emit([k, doc._id], scores[k]);
  }
};
```

Note that the structures of the original document could be optimised in my opinion. You have an array for scores but only have 1 element in it that is an object which has several keys for the names/players). This could be changed to:

```
{
    "_id": "2012-10-28",
    "scores": [
      {
        "name": "bob,
        "score": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "dole,
        "score": 5
      }
    ]
}
```

which would make it easier to manipulate.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: This is what I did eventually come up with, however it leads me to one question.  I know I can query this with `startkey=["bob"]&endkey=["bob",{}]` but if I wanted to get both _bob_ and _dole_ is there a way to do that in a single query?

Comment: Yes you could do `startkey=["bob"]&endkey=["dole"]` or `startkey=["AAA"]&endkey=["zzz"]`.

Comment: That would get everything in between as well, correct? Is there a way to only get those two keys?

Comment: You could try using `keys=[key1,key2]` but I am not sure `*` will work here with composed key e.g. `keys=[["bob", "*"],["dole", "*"]]`.